# Set non Required Number field to nothing using Apex

Tags: apex, fields, object

Is it possible to set non Required Number field to nothing using Apex?

If yes, than how? Because I can not just do the following:

```
update new An_Object__c(
   A_Field__c = ''
);
```

since it is expecting a `Decimal` value, but not a `String` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the field to `null` to make it blank (rather than zero).

This applies to field data types other than `Boolean` (Checkbox fields), which is always either `true` or `false`.